# How to bind the button content into tool tip's Radiobutton?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Actually I wanna bind the content part of radio button into the tool tip's radio button
i am a beginer in xaml so jus for practice i want to learn it...for better practice of Data Binding.. my code is as follows :

```
    <Button Name="BtnDemo"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Content="Hello Dear!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip >
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock Name="txbDemo" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Brown" Text="Tool Tip Of Hello Button"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="This Is The Tool Tip Of Hello Button...!"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding Content,ElementName=BtnDemo,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" IsChecked="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

i wanna do it without c# or VB.net...
Thanx In Advance....

Comment: Can you describe what exactly isn't working, please?

Comment: Actually This , <RadioButton Content="{Binding Content,ElementName=BtnDemo,UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" IsChecked="True"/> is not happening....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button Name="BtnDemo"  Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Content="Hello Dear!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Name="txbDemo" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Brown" Text="Tool Tip Of Hello Button"/>
                <TextBlock Text="This Is The Tool Tip Of Hello Button...!"/>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Path=Content}" IsChecked="True"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```